# How to find out path of Boost library for manual package build and installation?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, makefile

I am using Windows subsystem for linux for Ubuntu and I am very new to this. I am trying to build the program (AutoDock Vina) from its source code provided on GitHub - [GitHub Link](https://github.com/ccsb-scripps/AutoDock-Vina).

In its installation procedure - [provided here](https://autodock-vina.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#building-from-source), it's mentioned that -  **To compile the binary (you might need to customize the Makefile by setting the paths to the Boost library)**

[Makefile](https://github.com/ccsb-scripps/AutoDock-Vina/blob/develop/build/linux/release/Makefile) has the following code written in it -

```
BASE=/usr/local
BOOST_VERSION=
BOOST_INCLUDE = $(BASE)/include
C_PLATFORM=-static -pthread
GPP=/usr/bin/g++
C_OPTIONS= -O3 -DNDEBUG -std=c++11
BOOST_LIB_VERSION=

include ../../makefile_common
```

I had previously installed Boost and SWIG using apt-get command as mentioned in the manual.
`sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev swig`

When I tried to find out location of Boost library, I found that at following two places boost related files are there -

1. /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ and
2. /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ (these two folders have many files having names starting with `libboost`)
3. /usr/include/boost/ (this appears to be main folder for boost)

But, I tried many combinations to the `BASE` value in Makefile, but in all cases, after building the files, I see the executable named Vina (as expected) is built in the folder but  when I try to run the same on terminal, I get command not found error.

Please help me with this - **how to find out Boost related values for Makefiles?**

**Edit 1** - After reading the comment from @MadScientist, I have realized it's not a problem of Boost library but the issue I am facing is because of `PATH` not set. So I will follow his comment and proceed.

Comment: If you build the files and don't get errors and get an executable as expected, why do you think the build can't find the Boost-related files?  You did a great job describing your environment, right up until the very end when instead of telling us exactly what the problem was you petered out with "I get a command not found error", which is not specific enough.  Please show (via cut and paste) _exactly_ what command you typed and _exactly_ what error messages you got, not paraphrased or elided.  Then we can help.

Comment: @MadScientist thank you for your comment sir. After reading your comment, I checked again, and I realized that in fact the executable files (vina & vina_split) both are created and working fine in the release folder but not in other places. So, it should be Path problem (like in windows we set Path in Environment, I am yet to learn how to do the same in Ubuntu). I am so sorry for this stupid/incomplete question. I will close/delete it after you have read my comment

Comment: In a POSIX system, the environment variable is `PATH`.  Unlike on Windows, the shell will not search the current working directory by default: if the directory doesn't appear in the `PATH` variable it won't be searched.  Most systems do NOT put the working directory (`.`) into `PATH` because it's a security risk.  So, if you see a program locally you want to run, just give the path to it, like `./vina` (or whatever directory it's in).

Comment: ok sir, I got your point. Thank you very much for your time and support.